# position of words in VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to make a program that shows a keyword's position(s) in a string

my program :

```
Sub Button1Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim text1 As String = textBox1.Text
    Dim keyword As String = textBox2.Text
    Dim Array1() As String = text1.Split(" ")

    For Each item In Array1 
        If item = keyword Then
            For c = 1 To Array1.Length
                Dim input As String
                input = c
                listbox1.Items.Add("your word appears in the positions" & input)
            Next
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

But it does not display the position of that specific word but just the position of every word. Any1 help?

Comment: You're not showing all the code.  Can you clean up your messy code and provide *all of the relevant code*?

Comment: That cannot compile as is.  It is missing an `End If`.  And perhaps the Handles clause for the event

Answer (score 0):

Using the method provided by the .Net framework called `.IndexOf("<yourWord>")`, you can find the position of a word in VB.Net. If a word exists more than once in a string, use a loop which searches for the word, returns the position of it to an array, then cuts the string to that position and starts over again. At the end, you get an array with all positions of the word you were searching for.

Comment: There is an overload of [`String.IndexOf`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7cct0x33%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that takes the start position, so no need to cut the string up to find the next occurrence.

Comment: Oh right. Last time I have used this method was ages ago. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this.... it should give you some ideas....

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Module Module1

Sub Main()
    Dim Pattern As String = "The"
    Dim Test As String = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"

    For Each m As Match In Regex.Matches(Test, Pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("'{0}' :: occurs at position {1}", m.Value, m.Index))
    Next
End Sub

End Module
```